# The black frame around App ICON when App run on the iPhone

Tags: ios, icons

I have set the multiple size of icon in `AppIcon` of `Images.xcassets`.

And set **Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name** to **AppIcon**.

[image]

But when the App run on my **iPhone 5c** , it has a black frame around the icon like the following picture.

[image]

Did I missing something ?

Answer (score 3):

From iOS7: Avoid transparency. An app icon should be opaque. If the icon’s boundaries are smaller than the recommended sizes—or you use transparency to create “see-through” areas—the resulting icon can appear to float on a black background, which tends to look especially unattractive on the beautiful wallpapers that users choose

Check if there is any transparency present in the icon, if yes, please remove it.

You should avoid rounded corner icon, because Apple applies masks to your icon image for this. Provide a sqaure-ish icon of dimensions 120x120 pixels..

For more information go through [HIG Guidlines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH19-SW1)